# Unwanted change in speed of rotating camera view

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, xna-4.0

I have the following code in Xna 4,0:

```
void Rotate(Axis destination, float Speed)
    {
        if(destination == Axis.X)
        {
            if(CameraLookAt.X >= 0.0f - CameraPosition.X && CameraLookAt.Z < 0.0f - CameraPosition.Z)
            {

                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X >= 0.0f - CameraPosition.X && CameraLookAt.Z > 0.0f - CameraPosition.Z)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X < 0.0f - CameraPosition.X && CameraLookAt.Z >= 0.0f - CameraPosition.Z)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X < 0.0f - CameraPosition.X && CameraLookAt.Z < 0.0f - CameraPosition.Z)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
        }

        if(destination == Axis.Z)
        {
            if (CameraLookAt.X >= 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z < 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if (CameraLookAt.X > 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z >= 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if (CameraLookAt.X < 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z >= 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if (CameraLookAt.X < 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z < 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
        }

        if (destination == Axis.MX)
        {
            if(CameraLookAt.X > 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z <= 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X <= 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z < 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X > 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z > 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z += Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X <= 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z > 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
        }

        if(destination == Axis.MZ)
        {
            if(CameraLookAt.X > 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z <= 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X < 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z <= 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X <= 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z > 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X -= Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed;
            }
            if(CameraLookAt.X > 0.0f && CameraLookAt.Z > 0.0f)
            {
                CameraLookAt.X += Speed;
                CameraLookAt.Z -= Speed; 
            }
        }
    }
```

It must turn the camera view when the player changes direction. I am calling it in Update Method like `Rotattion(Rotation_Task, 20.0f);` Rotation_Task is Variable which specifies where must the camera be watching and is changed every time an arrow button on the keyboard is pressed. The first time the camera is turned when arrow key is pressed there is no problems, but the every next turn is much slower it is like the Speed variable is around 1.0f.
Do you see problems in this method which can be causing this slowing.

The moving speed of the player doesn't change so the problem is not in the speed of the computer

P.s axis is enum
P.s1 it is 1-st person and the player is only camera

Comment: Are you trying to make a 1st person camera or a 3rd person camera or other?

Comment: A first person. And the player is only camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're looking at the center of your screen. Now you move your `lookAt` point by 10cm to the right so your eyes angle changed by some value. Now let's say you've done this dozens of times so your `lookAt` point is 10 meters to the right - when you move it again by 10cm then you'll get much smaller change in your eyes angle.

This is why your `lookAt` approach is not the best one for 1st person cameras. You could try to fix this with some trigonometry, computing the needed `lookAt` offset with `tangens` function, so you get the correct angle change, but then you'll get into problems near the infinity and at the end you'll get many complicated ifs as you have already :).

I'd suggest to store your X/Z rotation angles somewhere. Then in your function you'll just add/subtract your `Speed` from X or Z angle. Then, depending on your exact API (I don't know Xna) you have such options:

- If you can set the camera rotation directly (you may not be able to do so with a 'look at' camera) you just set your X/Z values or build a rotation matrix from them to use.
- If you need to stick with the current `lookAt` approach - you may build a unit vector and rotate it around both axes, then add it to your camera location and you'll get the correct `lookAt` point.

If you still have problems doing it in Xna and/or you lack some functions please let me know what can you use there and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the answer. I will try it.